# Prestashop: Pass data from js file to controller to custom page

Tags: ajax, controller, request, prestashop

I'm having difficulty passing the value from my personal js to the controller and recovering it on the personal tpl page.

This module will serve to customize product after some selections and fields to fill out.

The selections pass from tabs to tabs.
The problem is that I can't get the value {$ var}

I have:

- JS in root->modules->modulename->views->js->namejsfile.js
- CONTROLLER in root->modules->modulename->controllers->front->controllername.php
- VIEW in root->modules->modulename->views->templates->front->filename.tpl

in JS

```
$('#send').click(function(){
            var ciao = 'cioaa';
            var myUrl = prestashop.urls.base_url + 'index.php?fc=module&module=configuratore';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                cache:false,
                url: myUrl,
                data: {
                    ajax: true,
                    datas:ciao,
                    action: 'fromAjax',
                },
          })
          .done(function() {
            console.log('Success!');
          })
          .fail(function() {
            console.log('error');
          });
});
```

in PHP

```
class ConfiguratoreTaskModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function initContent()
    {


        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate('module:configuratore/views/templates/front/task.tpl');
    }
    $this->fromAjax();
}

public function fromAjax()
{
    $mVar = Tools::getValue('datas');
    return   $this->context->smarty->assign(array('var'=>$mVar));
}
```

in TPL

```
{$var}
```

Comment: I corrected by adding the controller to the url. `&controller=task` I succeed as a response in the consol log but I don't see the parameter on the custom page. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?

public function fromAjax()
{
    $mVar = Tools::getValue('datas');
    $this->context->smarty->assign(array('var'=>$mVar));
    $templateFile = 'module:configuratore/views/templates/front/task.tpl';
    $html = $this->fetch($templateFile);
    die($html); // pass to JS
}
```

in JS:

```
.done(function(html) {
        console.log(html);
      })
```

Comment: No, doesn't work. response error with `Attempted to call an undefined method named "createTemplate" of class "ConfiguratoreTaskModuleFrontController"` and if chage to `setTemplate` the error begin `Call to a member function fetch() on null`

Comment: Oh sorry.I meant the method of use, not the functions I used.
The post has been updated

Comment: Thank's Mahdi. I changed your fetch in `$this->context->smarty->fetch` based on last version and now the error is on layout `Notice: Undefined index: layout`